# D3Plus - How to add labels to bar chart?

Tags: javascript, d3plus

I am drawing a simple bar chart using d3Plus. [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjzNQV) includes simple example code from the d3Plus webpage. The following code

```
  var visualization = d3plus.viz()
    .container("#viz")
    .data(data)
    .type("bar")
    .id("name")
    .x("year")
    .y("value")
    .draw()
```

Yields:

[image]

How can labels be added to each bar? I would like each bar to be labeled with its value.

EDIT: Not yet available https://github.com/alexandersimoes/d3plus/issues/354

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature will be available in the next public release of D3plus: https://github.com/alexandersimoes/d3plus/issues/354

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this:

http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/making-a-bar-chart

Search on this Site for "Labels" then you'll find your answer. It's well describe.

Comment: The documentation states that `.labels( Boolean | Object )` should be used to label shapes. But it seems to only affect the tool tip labeling.